# Insert a div and remove it within js function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a script here that requires a bit of manual work done.  The developer doesn't provides modification support and I am not exactly JS proficient so I need some help.  Basically the script below shows a woocommerce product image, and there's a preload function.  I need to insert a div called .temp-image before the preload_img.onload = function and remove the div within preload_img.onload

```
if ($(img).length > 0) {
    img.data('tm-current-image', false);
    var a = img.closest("a");
    var a_href_original = a.attr('href');
    main_product.on('tm_change_product_image', function(e) {
        var tm_current_image_element_id = e.element.attr('name'),
            $main_product = e.main_product;

        var clone_image = img.tm_clone(),
            preload_img = new Image();

        preload_img.onload = function() {
            $main_product.find('#' + tm_current_image_element_id + '_tmimage').remove();

            $main_product.find('.tm-clone-product-image').hide();

            clone_image.prop('src', preload_img.src).hide();

            img.hide().after(clone_image);

            clone_image.show();

            if (is_iosSlider) {

                setTimeout(function() {

                    is_iosSlider_element.iosSlider('update');

                }, 150);

            }

        };

        clone_image

            .attr('id', tm_current_image_element_id + '_tmimage')

        .addClass('tm-clone-product-image').hide(); //.show();

        preload_img.src = e.src;

        a.attr('href', e.src);

        img.data('tm-current-image', tm_current_image_element_id);

        if (is_yith_wcmg) {

            yith_wcmg.yith_magnifier('destroy');

            yith_wcmg.yith_magnifier(yith_magnifier_options);

        }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i am not clear your question but you can add div using this, suppose you want add div after this is div and you want to add div after this

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
      $(".test").append("<div id='specificdiv'>hello world</div>");
  </script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("<div id='specificdiv'>hello this is added div</div>").appendTo(".test"); 
</script>
```

or

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("<div></div>").attr('id','specificdiv').appendTo('body'); 
    </script>
```

and remove it

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $( "#specificdiv" ).remove(); 
    </script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $( "#specificdiv" ).empty(); 
    </script>
```